# Haskell - Find the longest word in a text

Tags: haskell, text, cpu-word

I've got a problem about to write a function to find the longest word in a text.

Input: A string with a lot of word. Ex: `"I am a young man, and I have a big house."`

The result will be 5 because the longest words in the text have 5 letters (young and house).

I've just started to learn Haskell. I've tried:

```
import Char
import List

maxord' (str:strs) m n = 
    if isAlpha str == True
    then maxord'(strs m+1 n)
else    if m >= n
        then maxord'(strs 0 m)
    else    maxord'(strs 0 n)

maxord (str:strs) = maxord' (str:strs) 0 0
```

I want to return `n` as the result but I don't know how to do it, and it seems there is also something wrong with the code.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here. Let's start with the syntax.

Your `else` parts should be indented *the same or more as the `if` they belong to*, for example like this:

```
if ...
then ...
else if ...
     then ...
     else ...
```

Next, your function applications. Unlike many other languages, in Haskell, parentheses are *only used for grouping and tuples*. Since function application is so common in Haskell, we use the most lightweight syntax possible for it, namely whitespace. So to apply the function `maxord'` to the arguments `strs`, `m+1` and `n`, we write `maxord' strs (m+1) n`. Note that since function application has the highest precedence, we have to add parentheses around `m+1`, otherwise it would be interpreted as `(maxord' strs m) + (1 n)`.

That's it for the syntax. The next problem is a semantic one, namely that you have *recursion without a base case*. Using the pattern `(str:strs)`, you have specified what to do when you have some characters left, but you've not specified what to do when you reach the end of the string. In this case, we want to return `n`, so we add a case for that.

```
maxord' [] m n = n
```

The fixed `maxord'` is thus

```
maxord' [] m n = n
maxord' (str:strs) m n = 
    if isAlpha str == True
    then maxord' strs (m+1) n
    else if m >= n
         then maxord' strs 0 m
         else maxord' strs 0 n
```

---

However, note that this solution is not very idiomatic. It uses explicit recursion, `if` expressions instead of guards, comparing booleans to `True` and has a very imperative feel to it. A more idiomatic solution would be something like this.

```
maxord = maximum . map length . words
```

This is a simple function chain where `words` splits up the input into a list of words, `map length` replaces each word with its length, and `maximum` returns the maximum of those lengths.

<sub>Although, note that it's not the exact same as your code, since the `words` function uses slightly different criteria when splitting the input.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

Try to split your task into several subtasks. I would suggest splitting it like this:

1. Turn the string into a list of words. For instance, your example string becomes

   ```
   ["I","am","a","young","man","and","I","have","a","big","house"]
   ```
2. `map length` over the list. This calculates the word lengths. For example, the list in step 1 becomes

   ```
   [1,2,1,5,3,3,1,4,1,3,5]
   ```
3. Find the word with the highest number of characters. You could use `maximum` for this.

You can compose those steps using the operator `(.)` which pipes two functions together. For instance, if the function to perform step 1 is called `toWords`, you can perform the whole task in one line:

```
maxord = maximum . map length . toWords
```

The implementation of `toWords` is left as an excercise to the reader. If you need help, feel free to write a comment.

Comment: Probably the optimal implementation of toWords is: "toWords = words".

Comment: @ben No. words would also count punctuation and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems

There is no termination for you recursion. You want to return `n` when you processed the whole input.

```
maxord' [] _ n = n
```

Syntax:

```
maxord'(strs 0 m)
```

this means that call apply `strs` with parameters `0` and `m`, and then use that as an argument to `maxord`. What you wan't to do is this:

```
maxord' strs 0 m
```

`m+1` should be `(m+1)`.

You might want to process empty strings, but `maxord` doesn't allow it.

```
maxord s = maxord' s 0 0
```

That should do it. There are a couple of subtleties. `maxord'` shoudln't leak out to the namespace, use `where`. `(max m n)` is a lot more concise than the if-then-else you use. And check the other answers to see how you can build your solution by wiring builtin things together. Recursions are a lot harder to read.